# Use of the existential quantifier over multiple individuals

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

I have a relatively simple logic problem. Basically, I want to state that there is an assignment of values  $x,y,u,v,z$ that makes the statement $P(x,y,u,v,z)$ false.

Should I write  $\exists x, y, u, v, z. \neg P(x,y,u,v,z)$ or $\exists x. \exists y. \exists u. \exists v. \exists z. \neg P(x,y,u,v,z)$, or something else?

Comment: The latter is fine, the former a well-understood notational abbreviation

Comment: You might want to avoid the '$.$' though, it tends to have a different meaning.... a space between variables and a colon or comma between the variables and body is more common.  $\exists x ~ y ~ u ~ v ~ z~:~ \lnot P(x, y, u, v, z)$

Comment: @DanielV: I'm curious what's the different meaning it tends to have? I personally use a full-stop only for ending a sentence. but I've seen many people put full-stops after quantified variables.

Comment: @user21820 The '.' is often used to indicate that everything to the right is grouped in parenthesis regardless of evaluation order.  So $\forall x . P(x) \land Q$ would mean $\forall x ~ (P(x) \land Q)$

Comment: @DanielV: Oh I see. Does "$:$" have the same connotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More generally:

> "$\exists x,y \in S\ ( P(x,y) )$" denotes "$\exists x \in S\ \exists y \in S\ ( P(x,y) )$", when $P$ is a binary predicate on $S$.

So what you have written are both conventionally understood as equivalent, and the former is easier to read. For an example of why it is preferable consider the following theorem:
$
\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}
\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}
$

> $\forall a,b \in \zz\ ( \neg \exists d \in \nn\ ( d > 1 \land \exists k,m \in \zz\ ( a=dk \land b=dm ) ) \to \exists x,y \in \zz\ ( ax+by=1 ) )$.

It would be way harder to read if it was written out in full.

In logic you might also frequently encounter further abbreviation such as "$\forall x_1,\dots,x_n$" denoting "$\forall x_1 \cdots \forall x_n$", when $n$ is a given natural number. Again, this is just for readability.